# how to send authorization details in pact Json Generation or to pact verfier in PACT PYTHON

Tags: python-requests, pact

how to send authorization details in MOCK service or to pact verfier in PACT PYTHON

when i call API thorugh soapUI it is working fine but when i run it mock Json through Pact verfier , it is faling since i am not senidng Authorization details in request header or not adding in pact verfier.
can u please help me how can send authorization details through request headers in PACT python?

```
def test_HappyPath (self):
            mockurl = 'http://localhost:1234'
            expected =  {body:true}
            pact.given (
                'Given there is a valid  form'
            ).upon_receiving (
                'fetch all the info '
            ).with_request (
                 'get',
                '/',headers={Authorization:'Bearer 58771381-333e-334f-9604-784'}
            ).will_respond_with(200, body=expected)
  with pact:
                result = callAPI ( mockurl )
            self.assertEqual(result, expected )
```

Request and Authroization Info:

```
 GET https: http....com/ /v1/ forms/83359274-7ad6-4
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    Authorization: Bearer 58771381-333e-334f-9604-ebf977ed7784
    Content-Length: 0
    Host: company.com
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_162)


OAUTH2.0: 
CSClientUser=username
CSClientPassword=pwd
CSClientIdendification=xxxx
CSClientSecret=fffff
CSAccessTokenURI=company.com/oauth2/token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read https://docs.pact.io/faq#how-do-i-test-oauth-or-other-security-headers as a starting point.

On the consumer side, what you have done is fine (although you might want a matcher if you are generating unique tokens).

On the provider side, you will want to pass the (as yet undocumented in pact-python) flag `--custom-provider-header` option to the verification process[1], which allows you to override one or more headers with dynamic values (in your case, a live auth token).

This is assuming of course that you can't *mock out the authentication system* during provider verification.

Under the hood, a separate service[2] is spawned to do this verification. There is more info on this feature in the link provided.

- [1] https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-python/#verifying-pacts-against-a-service
- [2] https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-provider-verifier#usage

Comment: Matthew Fellow - Thank you for providing the information. i will follow your links and try to implement it . will update whether it worked or not

Comment: Everything I've seen around authentication talks about using a header. Is there a way of doing this for an authentication token that is sent as a query parameter?

Comment: I don't believe Python has support yet, but the feature of other languages is called Request Filters which would allow you to do so. Perhaps you could raise a request on the repo?